# Nock intercepts request but returns empty object

Tags: unit-testing, mocha.js, fetch, interceptor, nock

I'm using [mocha](https://mochajs.org/) as the testing framework and I'm trying to mock up a `DELETE` request that uses [fetch](https://github.com/matthew-andrews/isomorphic-fetch) against an end point that returns HTTP status code `204`.

Here is the test code:

```
it('should logout user', (done) => {
  nock(<domain>)
    .log(console.log)
    .delete(path)
    .reply(204, {
      status: 204,
      message: 'This is a mocked response',
    });

  api.logout(token)
    .then((response) => {
      console.log('IS DONE?--->', nock.isDone());
      console.log('RESPONSE--->', response);
      done();
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log('ERROR--->', error);
    });
});
```

This returns the following output:

```
matching <domain> to DELETE <domain>/<path>: true 
(the above line being generated by the .log method in nock)
IS DONE?---> true
RESPONSE---> {}
```

As you can see the request is being properly intercepted as stated by the `log()`and `isDone()`nock methods, however the `response` object returned is an empty object, so it's not possible to make assertions about the returned HTTP status code  (in this example `204`)

Any idea what I might be missing here?, why does the `reply()` method return an empty object?

**UPDATE**

Here is the code for the `logout` method, the `remove` method is a wrapper for a `fetch` request using the `DELETE` HTTP method.

```
logout(token) {
  return remove(
    this.host,
    END_POINTS.DELETE_TOKEN,
    {
      pathParams: { token },
    },
    {
      Accept: 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
    },
  );
}
```

Comment: What's the code of `api.logout`? That does not appear to be something provided by `nock`. Seems to me there could be an error there.

Comment: It represents a `DELETE`HTTP method for the end point, which works fine and it seems to be correctly intercepted as shown in the output, I've updated the question to include the code, I did not include it before in order to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think 204 is not supposed to have a response [body](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#2xx_Success), so you may need to change it to 200. The server of course could return the response, but I think the fetch will not handle it. Other package like [request](https://github.com/request/request) will handle the body with 204 status, but this request package is for server-side only.

Also not sure what your wrapper does, but I think you need to get the response using response.json() promise. And mocha can also handle promises automatically, you can just return them. See a complete example below:

```
const nock = require('nock')
const fetch = require('isomorphic-fetch');
const request = require('request')

const domain = "http://domain.com";
const path = '/some-path';
const token = 'some-token';

const api = {
    logout: (token) => {
        return fetch(domain + path, {
            method: 'DELETE',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        });
    }
}

describe('something', () => {
    it('should logout user with 204 response using request package', (done) => {
        nock(domain)
            .log(console.log)
            .delete(path)
            .reply(204, {
                status: 204,
                message: 'This is a mocked response',
            });

        request.delete(domain + path, function(err, res) {
            console.log(res.body);
            done(err);
        })
    });

    it('should logout user', () => {
        nock(domain)
            .log(console.log)
            .delete(path)
            .reply(200, {
                status: 200,
                message: 'This is a mocked response',
            });

        return api.logout(token)
            .then((response) => {
                console.log('IS DONE?--->', nock.isDone());
                return response.json();
            })
            .then(function(body) {
                console.log('BODY', body);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log('ERROR--->', error);
            });
    });
});
```

This will output:

```
  something
matching http://domain.com:80 to DELETE http://domain.com:80/some-path: true
{"status":204,"message":"This is a mocked response"}
    ✓ should logout user with 204 response
matching http://domain.com:80 to DELETE http://domain.com:80/some-path: true
IS DONE?---> true
BODY { status: 200, message: 'This is a mocked response' }
    ✓ should logout user
```

Following deps used:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "isomorphic-fetch": "^2.2.1",
    "mocha": "^3.2.0",
    "nock": "^9.0.6",
    "request": "^2.79.0"
  }
```

I hope it helps.